# Mattermost compilation failed (Ubuntu 16.06)

Tags: npm, mattermost, pngquant

I'm trying to compile Mattermost on Ubuntu (I have Node 7.x installed, and even tried this with 6.x) but am getting the following types of errors:

```
 [701] ./images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png 471 bytes {60} [built] [failed] [1 error]
 [702] ./images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png 471 bytes {60} [built] [failed] [1 error]
 [703] ./images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png 471 bytes {60} [built] [failed] [1 error]
 [704] ./images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png 471 bytes {60} [built] [failed] [1 error]
 [705] ./images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png 471 bytes {60} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[1657] multi babel-polyfill ./root.jsx root.html 52 bytes {60} [built]
    + 2192 hidden modules

ERROR in ./images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png
Module build failed: Error: spawn /root/go/src/github.com/mattermost/platform/webapp/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1033:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
 @ ./root.html 1:945-999
 @ multi babel-polyfill ./root.jsx root.html
```

The complete error log is massive and I'll post it if need be, but I think this seems to be some problem with pngquant not being able to work om images. I'm going in circles and am almost at my wits' end. Can somebody suggest something?

**==Update==**

Upon further investigation, I found that the directory `/root/go/src/github.com/mattermost/platform/webapp/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor` doesn't exist. Why should that be? O.o

Comment: Some questions to help understand the problem:
1. What version of mattermost are you trying to compile? Or is this the master branch from github?
2. What command are you running which produces this output?

Comment: Hey @George. Yes, I used the master branch. The command that produced this was `make run`.

Comment: Sorry, somehow missed your reply to this. Did you get it working in the end? It looks like it's probably a transient error with installing npm dependencies, so probably pulling the latest master branch, then doing `make nuke` followed by `make run` again would fix it if not.

Comment: @George Nope, I abandoned it, and finally the project as well. :-| I'm not well versed in Node and didn't find it worth the effort to keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this issue myself yesterday. The solution was to update to the latest version of nodejs (specifically, of version 7).